# Python method not found after import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

This is an odd-ball problem. It is basic Python so it should have work. Any suggestion is most appreciate.

We have a "basic_train.py" file with:

```
def load_learner():
```

and we did the import

```
from fastai.basic_train import *
```

NO error there, but the "load_learner()" can not be found, e.g.

```
learn = load_learner(path)
```

got the error:

```
load_learner module not found
```

We even try:

```
import fastai
learn = basic_train.load_learner(path)
```

and:

```
from fastai import *
learn = load_learner(path)
```

and it got the same module not found error in both cases.

It is basic python, the "import" and "from ... import" execute fine, so it             should have work. Any idea why?

Comment: Could you provide pseudo code, pls? Also do you import from within the same folder?

Comment: please copy and paste the full error message as it is.

Comment: Please post an *exact* example that produces a "module not found" error for `load_learner`.

Comment: please show the directory structure of your files. "tree /path/to/your/directory" does that on linux.

Comment: Also, please post the exact error message. "load_learner module not found" is not an error message Python would produce. These details matter.

Comment: We feel a bit stupid for NOT checking the version. We were using the 1.0.36 version which does not have the "load_learner()" method. We should have done "!cat [path]/basic_train.py" and check it. "...a big DUH moment."

Answer (score 0):

We feel a bit stupid for NOT checking the version. We were using the 1.0.36 version on Google Colab which does not have the "load_learner()" method.

We should have done "!cat [path]/basic_train.py" on jupyter notebook and check it. "...a big DUH moment" when we didn't see the "load_learner()" method. Sorry :-(

So, we did "!pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/fastai/fastai.git", which get the latest 1.0.40 version

Comment: This didn't work for me ;( Can you see my [Git Hub](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/issues/3709) issue on it, please?